# Expansion of polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Expand the following:

$-4(5x - 3) ^2$

As for this one, factorise : $5(y^2 - 45) $

Can't it just be $5(y^2 - 9)$? Why is it $5 (y+3) (y-3)$

Comment: Check your brackets... I think $5(y^2-45)$ is meant to be just $5y^2-45$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Use the formulas

- $(a-b)^2 = a^2-2ab+b^2$
- $(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2$
- $a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$

**Example:** $(4x+3)^2$, then $a=4x$ and $b=3$ so $(4x+3)^2=(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2=(4x)^2+2\cdot 4x\cdot 3 +3^2= 16x^2+24x+9$

Comment: @Josh Which of the three expression above do you recognize in $(y^2-9)$?